# What is the reason or proper usage of "price" and "pricing"?

Tags: differences

Here are my examples:

> We need to change the price of this item.
>
> We need to change the pricing of this item.

To me the second option feels right but why?

Answer (score 8):

The two sentences are roughly equivalent, but not completely so.

**Price** means the amount of money one will charge to sell an item. "The price for this can of tomatoes is fifty-nine cents."

By extension, can mean what one has to give up to achieve something. "The price for success is losing your social life."

**Pricing** *can* mean the same thing (and can be used as a too-many-syllables version of the same word) but it can have the additional connotation of the strategy or system one uses to *set* prices. For example, deciding to hold a sale to coincide with a holiday, or to set [loss leaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_leader) (to take a loss on some items to get customers into the store), or to offer [free shipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_shipping) on certain orders.

*Tiered pricing* is where a company offers different levels of service for different fees. ("Dropbox's pricing strategy includes a free, basic service level, in the hope that customers will use the service and like it, and then decide to pay more for additional storage.)

The wikipedia article on [pricing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pricing) covers several of the factors involved in pricing strategies and setting.

Alternately, "pricing" can be a verb meaning to apply or determine a price", as in "I'm using the label gun to price these cans of tomatoes", or maybe "I'm pricing the items for the garage sale" (where "pricing" means "to decide on a price").